# compiling python for embedded linux_rt

Tags: python, embedded

I am targetting an embedded platform with linux_rt, and would like to compile cpython. I am not asking whether python is appropriate for realtime, or its latency. I **AM** asking about compiling under platform constraints.

I would like an interpretter embedded in a C shared library, but will also accept an exectuable binary if needs be.

Any C compiling ive done is for mainstream OS deployment, and i usually just hit make install. Im not afraid to get a little dirty, but am afraid of longterm maintenance and repeatability.

---

To avoid as much memory overhead as possible, are there any compiler configurations that can be changed from defaults? Can I easily strip sections of the standard library I know will not be needed?

---

Target platform has a 600 MHz Celeron, and 256mb RAM. The required firmware is built for a v2.6 kernel (might be 2.4). The default OS image uses Busybox, and most *standard* system libraries are minimally available. The root filesystem is around 100mB (flash), although I will have an external memory card mounted and can extended root onto there.

Python should have 70% Cpu and 128mB ram at most times, although I could imagine *sloppy* execution of the interpretter at times, and on RT linux, that could start to add up. Just trying to take precautions before I dive in.

Looking for simple Do's or Don'ts. Reference to similar projects would be great, but I really want to stick with CPython where possible.

*I do not have the target platform in the shop yet, so I cannot post any tests. Will have the unit in 2 weeks and will update this post, at that time, if needed.*

Answer (score 0):

make a VM with the target configuration to help you get started. VirtualBox or QEmu.  If you don't have a root FS one place to start is TinyCore, which is very small, configurable, but also can run on your laptop -- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/11023